# Check if path exist in Firebase using Angular2

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, observable

When I try to query the following path: af.datebase.list('emails/emailID/replies') I get an error because there's currently no replies object for the given email. Is there a way to check if the path exists and if not return an empty observable?

Error message:
*database.refFromURL failed: First argument must be a valid firebase URL and the path can't contain ".", "#", "$", "[", or "]".*

Comment: A ref to a path that doesn't exist returns an observable that emits an empty array. I just tried it in a Firebase app that I have and it works this way. You may have another problem. Please edit your question to add the code that you are actually running.

Comment: Thanks for that Carlos. Turned out I had another issue with my code. Thanks